# What is the api equivalent for kapt/annotationProcessor?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When we have multiple modules in an Android project, for example, we have a mylibrary module, and some other module apps that will include this mylibrary module in the dependency by `implementation project(':mylibrary')`

Then when we want to add library which will be used for all the modules, we will add the library dependency in the mylibrary's gradle dependency using the **api** instead of **implementation**. For example:

```
api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

Sometimes a library need an annotationProcessor to be included in the dependency.

```
kapt "org.example:example:1.0.1"
```

If I want to include this annotation processor in mylibrary's dependency and make it available to multiple modules, what do I use instead of **kapt**?

Answer (score 46):

`annotationProcessor` and `kapt` dependencies are not transitive and therefore, need to be declared for every  module in your project

Comment: how about with ksp?